# Dynamic css3-progress-bar-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using css3-progress-bar-rails in my rails app like this

```
 <%= progress_bar(33, :color => 'blue', :rounded => true) %>
```

to get a progress bar it works fine.But my requirement is to update this progress bar dynamically based on the ajax request.

My ajax request is like this

```
var url = '/cluster/data.json?database=<%=@database%>';
```

I am calling controller method in that i wrote a code to find all the data from the table.

```
 def data
   authorize! :read, AlphaCourses
   @json = AlphaCourses.all.to_gmaps4rails do |person, marker|
     marker.json({ :mid => person.id})
   end
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render :json => @json }
   end
 end
```

Can anyone help me to update this progress bar based on the query response.Otherwise give me suggestions to get dynamic progress-bar using any other gem or JQuery or any other.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Give me suggestions to get dynamic progress-bar using any rails gem or JQuery or any other.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that I'm googling around trying to find a solution to this and this is still blank after a year is not promising.